# Mostrar resultado rows en codeigniter

Tags: php, sql

Tengo una tabla llamada Zonas en donde existen tres zonas ( Zona 1 con el id 1, Zona 2 con el id 2 y Zona 3 con el id 3 )

En el modelo de codeigniter 4 llamao el precio de la zona 1 de la siguiente manera.

```
$query_zones = $db->query('SELECT * FROM zones where zones.id=1');

$zona1 = $query_zones->getFirstRow();
```

Y luego muestro el valor del precio de la zona con el id 1 de la siguiente manera.

```
<?= $zona1->price ?>
```

Hasta ahi todo bien , sin embargo debido a mi poco conocimiento en este framework y de hecho en php, no tengo idea de como llamar el valor del precio de la zona 2 y la zona 3 ...Agradezco a quien me pueda ayudar.

Comment: En la query podrías traér todas las zonas que necesites `SELECT * FROM zones where zones.id IN (1, 2, 3)`  y luego con un foreach recorrer el resultado. Deberías subir la estructura de la tabla "zones" y especificar que base de datos estás utilizando.

Comment: También deberías compartir el fragmento de código donde muestras el precio (no solo la linea de código).